# How do I style Text and Hyperlinks within a TextFlow in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I've tried all kinds of different selectors, but no matter what I use, my style seems to be ignored.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

My css is:

```
.hint {
    -fx-fill: red;
    -fx-text-fill: red;
    -fx-font-size: 10.0;
}
```

My FXML is:

```
<TextFlow fx:id="flowPortForwarding" GridPane.columnSpan="2147483647" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
                            <children>
                                <Text styleClass="hint" text="Port will be shown in tooltip after connecting to a" />
                                <Hyperlink onAction="#helpPortForwarding" styleClass="hyperlink" text="portforwarding" />
                                <Text styleClass="hint" text="gateway." />
                            </children>
                        </TextFlow>
```

A complete listing of my sources are here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45205679/Settings.fxml
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45205679/settings-style.css

Comment: No need to link to offsite resources, especially to code locations that are likely temporary and will disappear in the future.

Comment: Your sample works fine for me. `-fx-fill` is the correct attribute to color some text.  I don't have your background images (I don't need them either).  Without them the text doesn't show up as your offsite linked stylesheet displays white text on a white background.  For me, changing the `-fx-fill` in your offsite stylesheet to another color, such as blue, then loading the fxml up in SceneBuilder showed the text up as blue (as expected).

Comment: A) your stylesheet is broken B) it doesn't even contain the string `red` let alone the rule mentioned above C) If I combine the snippets above to a application it works. Therefore I'm voting for close.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I already had a selector ".hyperlink, .hint", so my introduction of a new selector ".hint" was being ingored.